# How do I specify Xwayland server options in CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, x11, wayland, gdm

I'm using a generic CentOS 8 install.  By default it uses Xwayland as its X server, and it doesn't listen on tcp.

A quick `ps aux | grep Xwayland` shows:

```
gdm         2431  0.0  0.2 1746156 65456 tty1    Sl+  May14   0:00 /usr/bin/Xwayland :1024 -rootless -terminate -accessx -core -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6
bennett     2965  0.0  0.3 1819324 112204 tty2   Sl+  May14   5:00 /usr/bin/Xwayland :0 -rootless -terminate -accessx -core -listen 4 -listen 5 -displayfd 6
```

The only place I can find that specifies these options is in `mutter-3.32.2/src/wayland/meta-xwayland.c`.  Specifically:

```
  manager->proc = g_subprocess_launcher_spawn (launcher, &error,
                                               XWAYLAND_PATH, manager->display_n
ame,
                                               "-rootless",
                                               "-terminate",
                                               "-accessx",
                                               "-core",
                                               "-listen", "4",
                                               "-listen", "5",
                                               "-displayfd", "6",
                                               NULL);
```

Can this be correct?  It's hard coded?

Surely there's something that can be done without re-compiling it, or using some sleazy wrapper, right?

-E

Comment: Post the output of "netstat -ltup".I would argue if it doesn't use tcp it shouldn't be called a X server. But then I don't know anything about xwayland or centos - only that centos is linux.

Comment: Xwayland is an X server, and it *can* listen to port 6000 (I'm told).  It just doesn't in its default CentOS configuration.  See: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/xserver.html

Comment: The [man page](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/xserver/-/blob/master/hw/xwayland/man/Xwayland.man) doesn't seem to expect `-listen tcp`. The option `-listen` was re-purposed by wayland. This [commit](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/ofourdan/xserver/-/commit/2aae187c7cdae217c001097a4e9265169ee2bea9) is about fixing this (with `-listenfd`), but I'm not clear on what the resulting situation is.

Comment: @ErikBennet: 6000 is the port. Look in /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc which should contain the startup options. Mine contains: exec /usr/bin/X -nolisten tcp "$@". I'm running Debian so your mileage may vary.

Comment: I read someplace (reliable?) that Xwayland responds to all of the options of Xserver.  This appears to not be the case on CentOS 8.  I'm not marking this as an answer, since I haven't the time to investigate further, and I hope I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to close this one out.  Whatever `Xwayland` is, it does not seem to be an `Xserver(1)`.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System

This is not a critique of Wayland; it's just that I require a window system called X.  So I switched.

If I'm wrong, please post, and let me know.